# Push-pull transistor - input current spikes and advantage over just an npn transistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, npn, mosfet-driver, push-pull

I have simulated the following circuitry in LTSpice:
[image]

Input Voltage pulse characteristics:
[image]

Questions:
1. What is the reason for the current spikes on the input resistor R2? Do I need to worry about this?

[image]

This is the corresponding current output on R1:
[image]

2. When driving an nchannel mosfet, my understanding is I need to use a push-pull transistor pair to be able to feed in more current to the mosfet to overcome its gate capacitance. But, in simulation, when I use just an npn transistor, the current output is the same as the push-pull pair. Is my circuit wrong?
   [image]

Comment: Have you considered the charge storage parasitics of the BJTs?

Comment: For (2)both circuits are driving the same unrealistic load. Put 1 or 2 nF across the load (to represent that gate capacitance) and try again.

Comment: tie your collectors to +- 10 volts, place a 100 ohm Rload to Ground, and make the input be 1MHz sinusoid centered about ground, at 2 volts PP.